# jQuery after reload not working each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, refresh

I want to ask you if someone can help me with this code.
Every time if I reload page on "teams page" my each function doesn't work. I don't know why, I tried more options about it but not gonna work. I used Angular and jQuery together.

Here is HTML:

```html
<div id="navbar-animmenu" class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="show-dropdown main-navbar">
    <div class="hori-selector">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
  <li id="nav-btn-wrapper" class="home-wrapper active">
  <a class="home-nav-btn nav-btn"
    routerLink="/"
    routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    >Home</a
  ></li>
  <li id="nav-btn-wrapper" class="teams-wrapper">
  <a class="teams-nav-btn nav-btn"
    routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/teams">Teams</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and jQuery code for adding or removing class "active" on li element:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  var tabsNewAnim = $('#navbar-animmenu');
  var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find('.active');
  var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
  var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();

  $(".hori-selector").css({
    "left": itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
    "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
  });

  $("#navbar-animmenu").on("click", "li", function() {
    $('#navbar-animmenu ul li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
    var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
    $(".hori-selector").css({
      "left": itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
      "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
    });
  });

  $('.nav-btn').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('teams-nav-btn active')) {
      $('#navbar-animmenu').css({ top: 0 });
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('home-nav-btn active')) {
      $('#navbar-animmenu').css({ top: '-14px' });
    }
  });

  $('.nav-btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('teams-nav-btn')) {
      $('#navbar-animmenu').css({ top: 0 });
    } else {
      $('#navbar-animmenu').css({ top: '-14px' });
    }
  });
}
```

I tried also this code:

```js
$('#nav-btn-wrapper').each(function() {
  if ($('.teams-nav-btn').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.teams-wrapper').addClass('active');
    $('.home-wrapper').removeClass('active');
  } else if ($('.home-nav-btn').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.home-wrapper').addClass('active');
    $('.teams-wrapper').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

but not gonna works.

I just need to make a function which detect if a element is active or not and then addclass active to li element. Of course after refreshing page also.

If somebody can help me I will appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I missed the point, if you want to have a sort of persisted information of what tabs are active after a refresh you have to implement something more as a local storage or route handling. Otherwise, you can consider using ngOnInit by Angular or some document ready by JS or Jquery.